# I need to put a label in the right hand corner of my popup in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, label

Here is my code. I have tried several things to get the label in the top right hand corner of the popup and make it stay there, but nothing has worked.
Thanks for your help!

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ValidationWPF.MainWindow"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ValidationWPF"
                Title="MainWindow" mc:Ignorable="d" 
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" d:DesignHeight="259" d:DesignWidth="420" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid Height="129" Width="345">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="514*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0" />
            <RowDefinition Height="251*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Content="Errors" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="132,12,0,0" MouseEnter="button1_MouseHover">

        </Button>




            <Popup AllowsTransparency="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=button1}" StaysOpen="True" AllowDrop="True" Name="PopUp1" PopupAnimation="Scroll">

            <Popup.Child>
          <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="3, 3, 0, 0">
            <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="3, 3, 3, 3">

                <TextBlock Background="Salmon">

                  <Label Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" MouseDown="mouse_DownHandeled" AllowDrop="False" Margin="100,100,0,0">
                    x
                    </Label>

                    <local:ValidationUserControl/>
                </TextBlock>      
            </Border>

        </Border>
         </Popup.Child>
            </Popup>

     </Grid>
</Window>
```

As you see, I have a popup with a label that has an X in it. The label is fully functional. Now I just need it to look like a normal popup with the label in the top right hand corner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextBlock Background="Salmon" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="150" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30" />
            <RowDefinition Height="120" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="AliceBlue" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" AllowDrop="False">
            X
        </Label>
    </Grid>                                
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: It did put it in the right hand corner, but it made my UserControl not work.